# JavaScript bugg (top offset of an element, automatic picks document top offset?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a JavaScript plugin, but it got a lagg, an I don't know the way to solve this. I tried multiple things for a couple of hours, but none of them worked. I also searched on the internet for an identical bugg, but again with no success.

So, here is a part of my code:

```
        affectedElements = $("*[al-affected]");

        // loop through every element and check by affected attribute
        affectedElements.css('position', 'absolute')
            .css('display', 'none');

        $(document).on('scroll', function() {
            for(var i=0; i<affectedElements.length; i++) {
                element = affectedElements[i];

                elementTopOffset = $(element).offset().top;
                windowTop = $(document).scrollTop();
                windowBottom = windowTop + $(window).height();





                console.log(elementTopOffset +", "+ windowTop +", "+ windowBottom);

                // When I put the function showElement here, then I got the right elementTopOffset value
                // showElement();


                if(elementTopOffset > windowTop &&
                   elementTopOffset < windowBottom) {
                    // When I put the function showElement inside the if function, the value of the elementTopOffset changes
                    showElement();
                }





            }
        });

        // Set optionals and shows the element
        function showElement() {
            effect = ($(element).attr('al-effect')) ? $(element).attr('al-effect') : 'fade';
            duration = parseInt($(element).attr('al-duration'));
            delay = ($(element).attr('al-delay')) ? $(element).attr('al-delay') : 0;
            $(element).delay(delay).show(effect, false, duration, false);
        }
```

- Maybe helpfull: The incorrect value that the elementTopOffset variable gets when the showElement() function is inside the if-statement, is the same value as the windowTop variable.

I hope that this is clear enough.

Comment: How you are using element variable in showElement method while it is not in public scope? or I am missing something?

Comment: *"JavaScript bugg"*..??

Comment: can't get offset of a hidden element (display:none), will always be zero. Same with dimensions - hidden element has no dimensions because it isn't taking up any space

Comment: Thank you Charlietfl. I didn't noticed this before. Problem solved now.